# Can I write two php function inside one common function

Tags: php

Im new on PHP coding and im currently involed in a project where in that assignment, im calling two functions known as close and activate project from two buttons close and activate, but now in order to increase the quality of the code i need to call both of those functions in one common function. but up untill now i failed to do it. can anybody help me on this

[image]

close function

```
public function closeProject($projectID, $username){
    $exc = $this->estConnection();
    $query = ("UPDATE dbunited SET STATUS = 3, closedate = TIME() WHERE ID = $projectID"); 
    $result_query = mysql_query($query, $exc);
    $this->MonitorActivity($username, $projectID, 'Close project');
    return $result;
}
```

activate function

```
public function activateProject($projectID, $username){
    $exc = $this->estConnection();
    $query = ("CALL add_table_sp($projectID)"); 
    $result_query = mysql_query($query, $exc);
    $exc = $this->restartConnection();
    if(false !== $result){
        $query = ("UPDATE dbunited SET STATUS = 2, executedate = IFNULL(excecutedate, TIME()), closedate = NULL WHERE ID = $projectID"); 
        $result = mysql_query($query, $exc);
        $this->MonitorActivity($username, $projectID, 'Activate project');
    }
    return $result;
}
```

i want to abstract common behavior into a 3rd method and call it, can anybody help me on this

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and should not be used (and will stop working all together in a future version of PHP). You should use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: thanks for your response, ill do it as soon as i fix this

Comment: Why would you combine both functions into one "to increase the quality of your code"? That violates a number of good coding practices. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns. Each method has a specific concern. You might be able to abstract common behavior into a 3rd method though and call that.

Comment: thats what i exactly want to do on my 3rd method, thank you for your advise, ill edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a (home-work?) assignment, I will not give you the complete answer, instead I will just point you in the right direction = Use [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

```
function switchProjectState ($projectID, $userName) {

    // now you can have the body of the activateProject function in the common function
    $activateProject = function () {
        // define the body of the activation function here
    };

    // now you can have the body of the closeProject function in the common function
    $closeProject = function () {
        // define the body of the close function here
    };

    // now you can have one function to do queries (DRY compliant)
    $doQuery = function ($sql) {
        // you should actually be using mysqli_ or PDO here .. but thats another subject
        $exc = $this->estConnection();
        return $result_query = mysql_query($sql, $exc);
    };

    // now you call the correct anonymous function based on project state (tracked in $_SESSION)
    if ( $_SESSION['project_is_open'] ) {
        $closeProject ($projectID, $userName);
    }
    else {
        $activateProject ($projectID, $userName);
    }    
}
```

If you use the $doQuery callback in the activate and close functions, you can improve the code quality a little, by making it [DRY compliant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) instead of repeating your $exec; $query; $result_query steps in each .. that code repetition is a horrible thing and you should always look for ways to remove code repetition. If you will be doing queries in other functions, then $doQuery must be made a normal separate function in the class of course, because other functions will not be able to reach the anonymous function in the controlProject function.

Project state of course, can be passed as a parameter if you don't want to track it in $_SESSION .. or you could read the project's status from the DB and then make the decision whether it should be activated or closed.

Comment: So this fixes the DRY issues, but violates the Separation of Concerns, plus it makes the name of the function pretty undescriptive.

Comment: :) Glad it does that. Hope the OP learns to do it even better.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the common code that you can abstract into something new, but it's hardly worth it. I'd seriously consider postponing this optimization until there is more code that is following a similar pattern and then deciding whether to move it into a base class or a specific helper class.

Common lines marked below:

Close function

```
public function closeProject($projectID, $username){
|>  $exc = $this->estConnection();
|>  $query = ("UPDATE dbunited SET STATUS = 3, closedate = TIME() WHERE ID = $projectID"); 
|>  $result_query = mysql_query($query, $exc);
|>  $this->MonitorActivity($username, $projectID, 'Close project');
    return $result;
}
```

activate function

```
public function activateProject($projectID, $username){
|>    $exc = $this->estConnection();
|>  $query = ("CALL add_table_sp($projectID)"); 
|>  $result_query = mysql_query($query, $exc);
    $exc = $this->restartConnection();
    if(false !== $result){
        $query = ("UPDATE dbunited SET STATUS = 2, executedate = IFNULL(excecutedate, TIME()), closedate = NULL WHERE ID = $projectID"); 
        $result = mysql_query($query, $exc);
|>      $this->MonitorActivity($username, $projectID, 'Activate project');
    }
    return $result;
}
```

May be combined into:

```
public function executeQuery($query){
    $exc = $this->estConnection();
    $result_query = mysql_query($query, $exc);
    return $result_query;
}

public function closeProject($projectID, $username){
    $query = ("UPDATE dbunited SET STATUS = 3, closedate = TIME() WHERE ID = $projectID"); 
    $result = $this->executeQuery($query)
    $this->MonitorActivity($username, $projectID, 'Close project');
    return $result;
}
```

The line that calls `MonitorActivity` may also be moved, but right now it's not possible because it's in a nested if statement in one place and not in the other. I cannot make the decision whether it makes sense to add that if statement to all places where the method is called.